# Position div under absolute picture with dynamic height

Tags: css

My problem is positioning a div under a "dynamic picture" and having dynamic content under the div positioned under the dynamic picture:

[Link to the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rDqny)

jsfiddle css classes ready to be filled in :

1. .belowPicture
2. .belowBelowPicture

HTML:

```
    <div id="wallDetailContent">     
  <section id="wallDetailMessage" style="width 100%"> 
     <img class="wallDetailPicture" src="http://web.scott.k12.va.us/martha2/dmbtest.gif">
     <div style="max-width:70%;">blah gik sig en tur, og købte blah med hjem</div>
  </section>
  <section class="belowPicture">
    <p class="wallByDate"> 20140126220550</p> 
    <p class="wallByBy"> af &nbsp; </p>
    <p class="wallByName"> Anders  </p>
  </section>
  <section class="belowBelowPicture">
      content (should be dynamic, able to fill all the height it need downwards.)
  </section>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wallDetailPicture{
    top: 5px;
    right : 5px;
    position: absolute;
    display:box;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    max-width:30%;
    max-height: 200px;
}
.wallByName{
    font-weight: bold !important; 
    color: blue;
    display:inline-block !important;
}
.wallByDate{
    font-weight: bold !important; 
    display:inline-block !important;
}
.wallByBy{
    display:inline-block !important;
}
.belowPicture{
     background:red;
}
.belowBelowPicture{
    background:green;

}
```

Goal look:
[image: image of the goal]

Comment: Why don't you make wallDetailMessage section absolute instead of picture if you want text to be aligned? Is there a reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mix `relative` and `absolute` positioning in as much as you can [absolutely position an element with a relativity position element](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/), but you can't do what you're asking with `absolute` positioning, because as soon as an element's position is affected by the position of another, that's `relative` positioning.

**EDIT:** You can achieve what you're after using `float` and `clear`: http://jsfiddle.net/nDvYv/1/

Comment: No problem. Also, if you're working on a grid based layout, you may want to check out Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/) and Foundation (http://foundation.zurb.com/) rather than building from scratch.